# getJSON callback is not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been working on a minecraft status bar for my site, and I have written up this code using my minimal knowledge of Javascript and jQuery. From what I've read it seems like it should be working fine.

```
var url = 'minecove.org'; // URL of Server to Query
var port = '25565'; // Port of the Server
$.getJSON('http://api.syfaro.net/minecraft/1.2/server/status?ip=' + url + '&port=' + port), function(data) {
    var online = data.online;
    var playerson = data.players.online;
    var maxplayers = data.players.max;
    if (online) {
        $('#online').text('Online').css('color', '#000000');
        $('#players').text(playerson + '/' + maxplayers + ' players online');
    }
    else {
        $('#online').text('Offline').css('color', '#333333');
        $('#players').text('No Players');
    }
}
```

I have two divs on the page, "online" and navigating to http://api.syfaro.net/minecraft/1.2/server/status?ip=minecove.org&port=25565 works fine, returning the JSON data. Am I just coding it wrong? According to the several tutorials I've read through this approach should work. I've also changed the JSON line to be `$.getJSON(http://api.syfaro.net/minecraft/1.2/server/status?ip=minecove.org)` to eliminate any errors in the variables above, but that doesn't work either. I would really appreciate some help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: You've the closing `)` in the wrong place. It should be after the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 semantic errors. One is closing a parenthesis prematurely, and the other is not closing the final parenthesis after the function. Your code should be:

```
var url = 'minecove.org'; // URL of Server to Query
var port = '25565'; // Port of the Server
$.getJSON('http://api.syfaro.net/minecraft/1.2/server/status?ip=' + url + '&port=' + port, function(data) {
    var online = data.online;
    var playerson = data.players.online;
    var maxplayers = data.players.max;
    if (online) {
        $('#online').text('Online').css('color', '#000000');
        $('#players').text(playerson + '/' + maxplayers + ' players online');
    }
    else {
        $('#online').text('Offline').css('color', '#333333');
        $('#players').text('No Players');
    }
});
```

I tested it and it's working fine.

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: There were *no* syntax error with the code (only semantic errors). Removing the initial `)` would have *caused* a syntax error. Thus, although the result is correct, the first sentence is not.

Answer (score 4):

You are being tricked by the comma operator (which is tricky because the result is still valid syntax).

Does something look wrong with the following?

```
$.getJSON('x' + url + '&port=' + port), function(data) {
   //..
}
```

It should. The parenthesis after the `port` should, in fact, be after the callback so that it is also passed as an argument.

```
$.getJSON('x' + url + '&port=' + port, function(data) {
   //..
})
```

Answer (score 0):

the function getJSON takes a function as an argument.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

```
var url = 'minecove.org'; // URL of Server to Query
var port = '25565'; // Port of the Server
$.getJSON('http://api.syfaro.net/minecraft/1.2/server/status?ip=' + url + '&port=' + port/*)*/, function(data) {
    var online = data.online;
    var playerson = data.players.online;
    var maxplayers = data.players.max;
    if (online) {
        $('#online').text('Online').css('color', '#000000');
        $('#players').text(playerson + '/' + maxplayers + ' players online');
    }
    else {
        $('#online').text('Offline').css('color', '#333333');
        $('#players').text('No Players');
    }
});
```

Comment: I was thrown off because my friend sent me an example that had the function outside the getJSON. I didn't even think to double check.